# Android removing the background after select?

Tags: android, background, bitmap, imageview

I'm wondering if I can remove my imageview background after I select an image
example .. 
the imageview has a background photo written in it insert an image 
and when I choose an image from the gallery or the camera
and it gets inserted in the imageview by the "choosenBitmap"
but the imageview background is still there , and I want to remove it

I have try "imageView.remove(background);"
and "remove.background"
but no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **one** of the following:

```
// API 15 or lower
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

// API 16 or higher
imageView.setBackground(null);

// Any APIs
imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
imageView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

One or another may work or not depending on your implementation.

Comment: Don't forget to click the little checkmark next to the answer if it helped you... it will help other people find the answer, and help you get better answers in the future! :)

Comment: Ooh , sorry I'm new .. clicked :D

Comment: I just tried imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null); and got the message it is deprecated. I used @rijul answer imageView.setBackground(null).

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.setBackground(null);
```

This is what that worked for me.